# SUM on different columns based on other columns values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I bet title is not saying clearly what I am trying to achieve as complete newbie but will try to explain my problem below and hope some one will find a minute to share their wisdom :)
Lets say we have a table called TYPES (Microsoft SQL Server) updated periodically ie every half hour. it consist of unique types, for each type there is number of offered transactions (if any) every update window (in reality it has millions of rows, hundreds of types and dozens of columns kept over a few years)
But to keep it simple:

| DateTime | Type | Offered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-04 09:00 | Type1 | 300 |
| 2021-11-04 09:00 | Type2 | 30 |
| 2021-11-04 09:00 | Type3 | 255 |
| 2021-11-04 09:30 | Type 1 | 244 |
| 2021-11-04 09:30 | Type 2 | 118 |
| 2021-11-04 09:30 | Type 3 | 90 |

I am trying to sum offered for a given day (24 hours period) for selected types (lets say type1 and type3) separately in one select if possible i.e.:

| DateTime | Type1_sum | Type3_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-04 | 5621 | 4521 |
| 2021-11-05 | 5234 | 3651 |

Many thanks !

Comment: So how do you arrive at the desired values, especially since your sample data only has dates for 2021-11-04? Note that naming columns the same as reserved words is not advisable as it requires they are [delimted] and don't convery any meaning.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(offered)
FROM Types
GROUP BY trunc(date), type` 

would be a starting point. But this would have a row for each type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by grouping on the date portion of column [DateTime] then using conditional aggregation:

```
select
    cast([DateTime] as date) as [DateTime],
    sum(case [Type] when 'Type1' then [Offered] end) as Type1_sum,
    sum(case [Type] when 'Type3' then [Offered] end) as Type3_sum
from YourTable
group by cast([DateTime] as date)
```

Comment: Hi Michael,  simple and  elegant, works perfectly! Many thanks! One more little question if I can, The Type column in matter of fact  just hold number ID of the actual type and is a foreign key referencing to other table,  lets call it  All_Types  where the string value of its name is kept. Now I'd like to join this table here and do the search by type name rather then its ID. can this be done ? as now I have to use :  sum(case [Type] when '18754' then [Offered] end) as Type1_sum, rather then sum(case [Type] when 'Type1' then [Offered] end) as Type1_sum,